# Getting country names with jVectormap World Map

Tags: javascript, html, jvectormap

I have a world jVectormap world map and I want have a script run in the onclick method for clicking on the countries. Is there any way to return the country name as opposed to the country code? And if there isn't, is there a way to convert the country code into a country name as opposed to running it through a long case / if statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
onRegionClick: function (event, code) {
     var map = $('#world-map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
     var name = map.getRegionName(code);
},
```

Comment: how to do this in pure javascript?